# Angular Material Design Sidenav: Flex changes the vertical position instead of horizontal position

Tags: angularjs, flexbox, angular-material

Default Material Design gives a sidenav width of 304px.  I am trying to implement material design's use of flex boxes, by adding in a `flex="66"` attribute inside the `md-sidenav` element.
When I did, it shortened the sidenav vertically, instead of horizontally.

It seems like I'm unable to override that 304px without pure CSS, which, although I can accomplish, is something I was specifically hoping to stay away from.

I haven't seen this concept referred to in the Material Design documentation.  Anyone else have this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you will look at angular-material.css as below

[image]

md-sidenav is displayed as

```
  display : none
```

when its closed & its displayed as

```
display : flex
```

when its visible.

If you want to change its width you need to write below lines in yr custom.css which you should load after loading angular-material.css

```
width : 500px !important;
min-width : 500px !important;
max-width : 500px !important;
```

replace 500 with yr custom value.